# How to secure Amazon RDS shared between accounts

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Shared RDS db instance should be available for limited set of the AWS accounts.

What is the best way to allow access to Amazon RDS db instance from limited set of the AWS accounts only?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well currently there is only one way on AWS to allow access to RDS from specific AWS accounts: 
1. create ec2 security group on AWS account which need to have access to RDS db instance
2. Grant access to created Amazon EC2 security group on DB security group, something like:

rds-authorize-db-security-group-ingress default  --ec2-security-group-name myec2group --ec2-security-group-owner-id 987654321021

This is documented by amazon approach, however there are limits on number of db security groups rules, so if you need to allow access from more than 20 or 25 aws accounts you will run into hard limits on AWS db security groups.